# Paypal Test Account Dispatch Fail

Tags: java, paypal, paypal-sandbox

Whenever I try to access the Paypal sandbox, after authenticating, it shows an error:

```
Sorry — your last action could not be completed
Dispatch Error, Check Log information
```

https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_dispatch-failed

Above is the link mentioned, which i see after login process.

I tried creating a new account, then I tried to access the sandbox with a different ID, but that didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this issue was solved already but for a temporary solution **Remove API Signature** from the backoffice and it will get you to paypal checkout.
see this forum for more information: [Paypal V2.x (using API details) stopped working (3/20/13)](http://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/233764-resolved-paypal-v2x-using-api-details-stopped-working-32013/)

Comment: i tried your solution, removed signature from API, but it gives exception java.lang.NullPointerException. still not able to get paypal checkout.